# Save hibernate object without fetching foreign key entities, save only by id

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

I'm saving an object "Product" with Hibernate to the database. The Product object has dependent objects not as an id. In the database it is saved as foreign keys. The code below is part of getting the dependent objects for the saving object Product. So each time when we save a product we do unnecessary calls to the database, because we already know the id's of the dependent objects. How can I do this in a better way?

```
        Rubric rubric = rubricRepository.findById(productRequestDto.getRubricId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(productRequestDto.getRubricId().toString()));
    User user = userRepository.findById(productRequestDto.getUserId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(productRequestDto.getUserId().toString()));
    Condition condition = conditionRepository.findById(productRequestDto.getConditionId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(productRequestDto.getConditionId().toString()));
    Color color = colorRepository.findById(productRequestDto.getColorId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(productRequestDto.getColorId().toString()));
```